# VBA opening up New Workbook and copying to last row

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I am writing a copy to last row code that seems to copy the same exact number of rows each time.

The code is to open up a new workbook, take a specific sheet from the new workbook, copy all the available data, and pasting it into the original workbook. My code is below

```
Dim wkb As Workbook
Dim wkbFrom As Workbook
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim path As String, FilePart As String
Dim TheFile
Dim loc As String
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim lr As Long
Dim lr2 As Long

FilePart = Trim(shPivot.Range("E17").Value)
TheFile = Dir(path & "*" & FilePart & ".xls")
Set wkbFrom = Workbooks.Open(loc & path & TheFile & FilePart)
Set wks = wkbFrom.Sheets(shPivot.Range("E15").Value)
Lastrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
lr = shCurrentWeek.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lr2 = wks.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Debug.Print lr
Debug.Print lr2

'Copies range from report generated to share drive and pastes into the current week tab of open order report
wks.Range("A2:N" & lr2).Copy wkb.Sheets("Current Week").Range("A4")

'Closes the workbook in the shared drive
wkbFrom.Close False
```

I am constantly getting 187 rows of data even if the "new opened Workbook" has only 167. And data fills in column "A" all the way to row 507. Help?!

Comment: I would imagine some cells in `wks.Range("A:A")` have spaces or other non-null values, which will impact the `End(xlUp)` function.  Also, are you sure `TheFile` has the expected file name, because you have a * in there, so you may not be pulling in what you expect.

Comment: Could you please explain the significance of the * in the code?

Comment: * is a catch-all character.  Assume `path` is "C:\Path\" and `FilePart` is "FileName" - in this context it will pull in any files that match this pattern: "C:\Path\" & *ANYTHING* & "Filename.xls".  For example, it would pull in just "C:\Path\FileName.xls" but will also match to "C:\Path\ThisIsNotTheFileYoureLookingForFileName.xls", and because you're using Dir, one or the other might be populating earlier in the Dir queue.

Comment: Thank you but I do not believe that is happening in this case. The `FilePart` is an extremely specific file with unique values so that cannot be possible, i think. Also, i do not detect any non-null values unless `="1"` can be considered non-null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had trouble getting the last row of data myself from some worksheets; here is code that I use now that seems to be most consistent for me.

```
objExcelWks.Range("A1").Offset(objExcelWks.Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Row
```

Maybe that will work?

Comment: Thank you! this code works however, it seems to be still populating to row 502 for some reason. Any ideas with that?